# Access violation while reading a JNI-ByteBuffer in C++ in 32-bit JVM on 64-Win 7

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, access-violation

I am trying to build a SIP client in Java. As SIP-framework I use doubango. To display the video I'm using OpenGL through JOGL, but that should not be important, because during testing I actually detached the ByteStream from JOGL.

First of all, the video works fine on Win 7 with a 32 bit VM. The libraries do not compile for 64 bit, so I have to use a 32-bit-VM on 64-bit-system, which I thought should work just fine. Unfortunately I get to see the video only for a few seconds, before it crashes with an "Unhandled exception at 0x774315de in javaw.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xdddddde9."

Debugging in VisualStudio revealed, that the exception occurs in the following line:

```
memcpy((void*)m_ConsumeBuffer.pConsumeBufferPtr, pBuffer, nRetsize);
```

(http://code.google.com/p/doubango/source/browse/branches/2.0/doubango/bindings/_common/ProxyConsumer.cxx#710)

So apparently the error happens after a few hundred calls to the method (because the video displays correctly for a while).

To narrow down the possible causes, I only implemented incoming video in my test.

The doubango gets the pointer to the ByteBuffer from my implementation in Java, like so:

```
videoFrame = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(frameSize);
consumer.setConsumeBuffer(videoFrame, frameSize);
```

The `consumer` is doubango's own `ProxyVideoConsumer` which I get from it at construction.

I am not too familiar myself with C++-Debugging, seeing as I'm more experienced with Java and Delphi, but I think I'm confident to say that there seems to happen some kind of heap corruption.

My current assumption is that the JVM's `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(..)`-function does not behave correctly when running a 32-bit JVM on a 64-bit machine, but of course I can be mistaken.

It might be interesting to note that in two of about 50 test runs, the video was stable for 5-10 minutes, without any degradation or apparent memory leak. But this "pseudo-randomness" is consistent with my experience with memory allocation issues in Delphi.

I'd be glad if someone could help me, as I've run out of ideas how to get this to run stable.

Regards,
CSp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I somewhat solved the problem myself. Apparently when the error occurs, the `pBuffer` is already freed/invalidated at this point. I traced the error so far, that the `sipSession` which contains the buffer is being freed by the JVM at random intervals, even if there is still a reference being hold within the JVM.

Putting the garbage collector into debug-mode also didn't reveal much, as it didn't log any intention to dispose any object at this point. Actually the error occurs after only a few seconds, so the GC didn't try to free anything at that point.

I found one instance, where I freed the `sipSession` prematurely, which reduced the frequency of the error, but all the other disposals have their stack-trace leading to the GC.